# How to edit a pulumi resource after it's been declared

Tags: pulumi

I've declared a kubernetes deployment like:

```js
const ledgerDeployment = new k8s.extensions.v1beta1.Deployment("ledger", {
  spec: {
    template: {
      metadata: {
        labels: {name: "ledger"},
        name: "ledger",
        // namespace: namespace,
      },
      spec: {
        containers: [
          ...
        ],

        volumes: [

          {
            emptyDir: {},
            name: "gunicorn-socket-dir"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Later on in my `index.ts` I want to conditionally modify the `volumes` of the deployment. I think this is a quirk of pulumi I haven't wrapped my head around but here's my current attempt:

```
if(myCondition) {
  ledgerDeployment.spec.template.spec.volumes.apply(volumes =>
    volumes.push(
    {
      name: "certificates",
      secret: {
        items: [
          {key: "tls.key", path: "proxykey"},
          {key: "tls.crt", path: "proxycert"}],
        secretName: "star.builds.qwil.co"
      }
    })
  )
)
```

When I do this I get the following error: `Property 'mode' is missing in type '{ key: string; path: string; }' but required in type 'KeyToPath'`

I suspect I'm using `apply` incorrectly. When I try to directly modify `ledgerDeployment.spec.template.spec.volumes.push()` I get an error `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Output<Volume[]>'`.

What is the pattern for modifying resources in Pulumi? How can I add a new volume to my deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to modify the resource inputs after you created the resource. Instead, you should place all the logic that defines the shape of inputs before you call the constructor.

In your example, this could be:

```js
let volumes = [
  {
    emptyDir: {},
    name: "gunicorn-socket-dir"
  }
]
if (myCondition) {
  volumes.push({...});
}
const ledgerDeployment = new k8s.extensions.v1beta1.Deployment("ledger", {
  // <-- use `volumes` here
});
```

Comment: I have the same question. It appears that a service bus namespace needs to be provisioned in Azure before I can access and apply its connection string to another resource's app settings.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a cyclic-dependency problem. Right now, the only way to handle this is to use a [Stack Reference](https://www.pulumi.com/learn/building-with-pulumi/stack-references/) that gets a value from the previous deployment. You then have to run `pulumi up` twice to get the desired state.